# How to attend my phone call from android phone in Mac?

Tags: google-play-store, 9.0-pie, macos, macrodroid

I am using Asus Zenfone Max M1 Pro with Android 9.0
I wanted to attend my phone calls from mobile in Mac machine running 10.15.1 macOS Catalina,

I have tried, Airdroid, it doesn't support.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/111194

Comment: https://www.xda-developers.com/scrcpy-control-android-on-pc

Comment: http://gizmostorm.com/how-to-receive-calls-on-mac-from-android